# Partial class spanning assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, partial-classes

In my framework project I have a class that represents tabs in a content management system. In some framewrok implementations it is desirable to extend this class with defintions of tabs that are specific to that implementation. I had though to do this by changing the CmsTabs class to be partial, like this:

```
namespace Framework
{
/// <summary>
/// Class containing common CMS Tab names
/// </summary>
public static partial class CmsTab
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Information Tab
    /// </summary>
    public const string Information = "Information";
```

And then creating a class with the same name and namespace in the assembly that implements the framework.

However, when I build the framework assembly, the CmsTabs class appears no longer to be partial - it's members are hidden in the implementing assembly when I add the partial class to that. When disassembled in Reflector, I get this:

```
public class CmsTab
{...
```

Is there something I need to do to make it retain its partial status, assuming that it is possible to do what I am trying to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't have a partial class span assemblies:

> All partial-type definitions meant to
>   be parts of the same type must be
>   defined in the same assembly and the
>   same module (.exe or .dll file).
>   Partial definitions cannot span
>   multiple modules.

[MSDN On Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to add new methods to a class in other assembly.

Answer (score 6):

Partial classes are a purely compile-time feature.
It is not possible to create a class definition that spans multiple assemblies.

Instead, you can make the class a non-static singleton, and allow implementations to inherit the class, add properties to it, and set the inherited version as the singleton instance.

If it's purely a collection of `const` strings, you can make it a `private partial` class, but add a link to the file in every project.